# slider not working with setInterval( ) function

Tags: android, cordova, slider, setinterval

I am loading news and notification in my PhoneGap app with setInterval( ) function. The news come one by one and load until the last news comes. The problem is that scroll bar on this page doesn't work until the news are load completely. What's wrong with it?

My code

```
function clearPackageTableSuccess(x) { 
    if(x=="c") { 
        //alert("x="+x); 
        clearInterval(myVar); 
    } else { 
        //alert("hhh"); 
        myVar = setInterval(function() { 
            newsloop() 
        }, 100); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the scroll bar? Doesn't it show or does it not let you scroll? And please provide us some of the code used for this. No way to guess what is happening with this explanation.

Comment: yes i am talking abt scroll.it doesn't let me scroll down ..function clearPackageTableSuccess(x){
 if(x=="c")
 { //alert("x="+x); 
 clearInterval(myVar);
 }
 else{
 //alert("hhh");
 myVar=setInterval(function(){ newsloop() }, 100);
 }
}